# How do I check which terminal I am using in Ubuntu?

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I have Ubuntu on my machine. I am running awesome Window manager on top of it. How do I check which terminal I am using? Is there a command for it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what OP considers the "terminal" to be.  The usual response would point out the *connection* or the terminal *device*:

- the [`who`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/who) command (particularly `who am i`) shows the connection.  For example:

  `$ who
  tom      pts/1        2015-06-23 18:06 (somehost:S.0)
  tom      pts/2        2015-06-23 18:09 (somehost.somewhere.net)
  $ who am i
  tom      pts/2        2015-06-23 18:09 (somehost.somewhere.net)`
- the [`tty`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tty) command shows the device, e.g.,

  `$ tty
  /dev/pts/2`

Then again, the OP might want to know which terminal *program* is being used.  There is no standard method (in particular, looking at the `TERM` environment variable is pointless).  One might follow the chain of process-IDs back in a `ps -ef` listing to find the corresponding terminal program which is running the shell (see for example *[How to find out the user of parent shell inside a child shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928112/how-to-find-out-the-user-of-parent-shell-inside-a-child-shell/30928315#30928315)*).  That does not always work, e.g., if you are asking about a terminal where you have ssh'd into the current machine.

Answer (score 1):

The command you're looking for is `ps -p $$`, I believe. Not sure if it's 100% universal for all shells, but it worked on the ones I tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question for [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/):

[How to check which shell am I using?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590899/how-to-check-which-shell-am-i-using)

The accepted answer there says to run:

`echo $0`

But there are more details so I'd recommend reading that.

Comment: I don't think this tells you which version you are using.  It tells you the version info of the shell sh.  For example, I have sh and zsh shells on a system.  I can run `sh --version` and `zsh --version` to get info, but not to tell me which I'm using.

Comment: Note, the link you added has some good info.  One comment says ```$0 is the name of the running process. If you use it inside of a shell then it will return the name of the shell. If you use it inside of a script, it will be the name of the script```  This seems like good info.